# Ordering multiple files (in the same folder) by end numeric digit - using R

Tags: r

I have two series of pdf files within the same working directory and I am using Windows. Both series have the same unique numeric identifiers as the end digit, however, their starting letters are L and M. They are, by default, ordered alphabetically:

L14_1

L14_2

L14_3

L14_4

M__1

M__2

M__3

M__4

and I need them to be ordered like this:

L14_1

M__1

L14_2

M__2

L14_3

M__3

L14_4

M__4

I am new to R coding and I have done some searching for similar questions and I haven't been able to come up with anything.

There are likely to be around 2000 files in total, (~1000 of each series). Is anyone able to help me out with this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
v1[order(as.numeric(sub('.*_', '', v1)))]
#[1] "L14_1" "M__1"  "L14_2" "M__2"  "L14_3" "M__3"  "L14_4" "M__4"
```

Suppose the order is different than you showed

```
v2[order(as.numeric(sub('.*_', '', v2)),substr(v2, 1,1))]
#[1] "L14_1" "M__1"  "L14_2" "M__2"  "L14_3" "M__3"  "L14_4" "M__4"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("L14_1", "L14_2", "L14_3", "L14_4", "M__1", "M__2", "M__3", 
"M__4")

set.seed(24)
v2 <- sample(v1)
```

Your `v1` might be

```
v1 <- sub('.pdf', '', list.files())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. There are likely to be around 2000 files to sort this way, (~1000 of each series). I will give your code a go, thanks!

Comment: @LH01 My solution was based on the pattern you showed.  If it is different, then we need to modify the code.

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks for your help once again - the code worked great in the R console, however, didn't manage to change the order in the file directory. I'll keep working on it. Cheers

Comment: @LH01 Sorry, i didn't understand it clearly.  May be you need to assign to some object `v3 <- v2[order(as.numeric(sub('.*_', '', v2)),substr(v2, 1,1))]`

Comment: It's all good - perhaps my question wasn't phrased that well. Thanks for your new suggestion - I've given it a go and the order is still the same in the file directory. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @LH01 If the file names are the same, I guess the order in the file directory should remain the same.

Comment: @LH01 For example `indx <- order(as.numeric(sub('.*_', '', v1))); v1New <- v1[indx];  v1New <- paste(seq_along(v1New), v1New,sep="_")` (not tested)